# cannot run a file in linux, /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, linux

OS: Linux(running inside docker)
node version: 10.22.1

I have the executeJs file below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var path = require('path');

var apJsFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../app.js'); //app.js is working correctly

require(appJsFile);
```

When I try to execute it `./executeJs` it throws the error: `: No such file or directory`

- I checked if the node was installed, by running the `node -v` command and it returned `10.22.1`
- I checked where was the node installed by running the `which node` and it returned `/usr/bin/node`
- I checked the path variable by running `echo $PATH` and it returned `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

I don't understand why shebangs is not working `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

I will appreciate any help in solving this issue.

```
# cat /node/scraper/bin/scraper
#!/usr/bin/env node
var path = require('path');
console.log(path);
var scraperJsFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../scraper.js');
console.log(scraperJsFile);
require(scraperJsFile);
# which node
/usr/bin/node
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# ./node/scraper/bin/scraper
/bin/sh: 72: ./node/scraper/bin/scraper: not found
# /usr/bin/env
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
HOSTNAME=84ad4665cc48
HOME=/root
OLDPWD=/node/scraper/bin
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
PWD=/usr/bin
# cd /node/scraper/bin
# ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 13 14:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jul  8 16:03 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  183 Jul 13 14:46 scraper
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  187 Jul 13 12:52 scraper.bak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  156 Mar 16 17:34 scraper.bat
# ./scraper
/bin/sh: 81: ./scraper: not found
```

Comment: Where is `env` located? Why use the shebang if you know where the version of node you want is located? Why use the wrapper if you’re running `app.js`?

Comment: This script is used  to start a process(`Why are you using wrapper`),   I don't want to modify the script since is shared with many others and it seems to be working, I want to make it work on my computer (`Why use the shebang if you know where the version of node you want is located`)

Comment: env is located at /usr/bin

Comment: Then you'll likely need to include more information, including the formatted output of the above information, cut and pasted from the container's shell.

Comment: Thank you for the time you are taking for helping me with this problem. I added the screenshot above about the information from the container shell. Tell me if you want me to run any other command.

Comment: Not a screenshot, formatted text. [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) You redacted what isn't found and you didn't show that the file existed. Your script looks for whatever you erased at `..` and you're trying to run it from `.`. There's no way to know if it's the same thing because you covered up the actual information :shrug: Nobody cares what your file is called or where your home directory is.

Comment: Sorry for that. I added the full content in the post text.

Comment: Canyou run /usr/bin/env?

Comment: I run the command and added the output in question.

Comment: The output says the file you’re running doesn’t exist. Does “./node/scraper/bin/scraper” exist? In your current working directory? It doesn’t align with what “env” shows for the old working directory—I think you’re running the wrong command.

Comment: I added some more commands that proves /node/scraper/bin/scraper exists. You can check them in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with why the shebangs for the node was not being recognized inside Linux Docker container was the content formatted in windows style for the `executeJs` file. This came due to the mounted volume of the docker container with the host system. Since my host system is Windows it had formatted `executeJs` in windows formatting style. I changed the formatted text style to Linux and everything is working correctly.

I opened the file with the vi editor and pasted the content and was able to run the `executeJs` file.